# skip items while iterating over list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, slice

I have been reading class objects from a txt file and stored the information in a list. My question is if I want to print out the first attribute but skip one row can it be possible. Say that the textfile is like this:

```
    Activity Time  Location
    Football  8-9  Pitch
    Basketball 9-10  Gym
    Lunch  11-12  Home
    Reading  13-14  Library
```

I want to do a for-loop that gives me the first attribute of the list but skip one row. For example writing:

```
for i in list:
    print(i.activity)
```

#gives me all the activities, But I want to get Football, lunch, reading without basketball

Is this possible? If so I would appreciate an easy code. I dont need anything advanced

Comment: maybe `for i in your_list[::2]:`? This will iterate over every other item in the list. Don't use `list` as name, it's a built-in function.

Comment: My list is bigger than i wrote. I just wrote an example so [::2] would skip more elements than I want.

Comment: Is it only one index that you want to skip? Or many, on different positions?

Comment: One specific index, then I want everything to continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sure but you should name your python list something else than `list` since `list` is a keyword in python  :

```
row_to_skip=1

for i in range (len (my_list)):
    item=my_list[i]
    if (i==row_to_skip):
        continue
    print(item.activity)
```

Comment: Friendly suggestion, if I may.  This line: `range (0, len (my_list))` should read: `range(len(my_list))`.  As both `range` and `len` are functions, and zero is the default starting point for `range`.

Comment: i agree ! it's more elegant .

Comment: This was great! Just one question: my list contains different times for example football 8-9, I still want to skip the second row as you did however I want to add my conditions that for example: print out football if the user writes that he comes at 8 and leaves at 9. I made two variables where I placed my inputs, but it didnt work everything was printed out (except the skipped row). Do you know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible:

Inside your loop add the condition

```
i = 0
for item in list:
    if i!=1:
        print (item.activity)
    i += 1
```

So in the second iteration nothing would be printed

Comment: Thanks, could you specify with an example? I write it like this:                                     
for i in list:
        if i == 1:
            continue
            print(i.activity) #But nothing gets printed out

Comment: @Rezaamin Perhaps you have `i += 1` below `continue`, in which case `i` never gets incremented beyond `1`? Instead of doing as above, try `for i, item in enumerate(list):`, then you do not have to increment (or initialize) `i` yourself.

Comment: The guy above me is right - make sure the initializing for i is done anyway, doesn't really matter how, you can do as he suggested or as I did

Comment: @jmd_dk I did like this but it didnt skip the row I wanted. I got all attributes printed out.                                                                           for i, item in enumerate(djur):
        if i != 2:
            print(item.activity)

Answer (score 0):

The example below simply reads the text string (`text_`), and uses the `list.pop()` function to remove the second element (after the header). In this case, the 'Basketball' row.

Then, another simple list comprehension creates the `activities` list which contains the first element of each row, and skips the header row.

Example code:

```
text = [i.strip().split(',') for i in text_]
text.pop(2)

activities = [i[0] for i in text[1:]]
```

Output:

```
['Football', 'Lunch', 'Reading']
```

Setup:

**Note:** This block is not required for functionality.  Only used to create the `text_` list from a string.

```
import io

txt = """Activity,Time,Location
Football,8-9,Pitch
Basketball,9-10,Gym
Lunch,11-12,Home
Reading,13-14,Library
"""

with io.StringIO(txt) as h:
    text_ = list(h)
```